# Why doesn't display: block on an <img> element set space to be reserved like other elements?

Tags: html, css, image, display

```css
img {
  background-color: lightblue;
  display: block;
}

.d1 {
  background-color: blue;
}

.s1 {
  background-color: orange;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://placehold.it/50x20">
<div class="d1">Test1</div>
<span class="s1">Test2</span>
```

Above, I am experimenting with `display: block;` property on various tags. I set it on `img` and `span` but, as I see, the image is not extended to the far right as `span` is... Why is that so? Ty

Comment: If you inspect the element with your dev tools and hover over the image, do you see the space being reserved for it by the browser?

Answer (score 1):

For an accurate explanation you need to refer to the specification and more precisely the part dealing with *block-level replaced element* since `img` is a replaced element<sup>1</sup> having a computed value of display equal to block:

> The used value of `width` is determined as for inline replaced elements. Then the rules for non-replaced block-level elements are applied to determine the margins.<sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#block-replaced-width)</sup>

Then for *inline replaced elements*

> If `height` and `width` both have computed values of `auto` and the element also has an intrinsic width, then that intrinsic width **is the used value of 'width'.**

Your image has an intrinsic width equal to `50px` so it will get used. You can only override it by explicitely specify a different width (`100%` if you want full width)

---

`span` and `div` are non-replaced element so their width is defined as follow:

> The following constraints must hold among the used values of the other properties:
>
> `'margin-left' + 'border-left-width' + 'padding-left' + 'width' + 'padding-right' + 'border-right-width' + 'margin-right' = width of containing block`
>
> If `width` is set to `auto`, any other 'auto' values become `0` and 'width` follows from the resulting equality. <sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#blockwidth)</sup>

You have all the value set to auto so we make everything 0 and we obrain `width = width of containing block` which is your full width behavior.

---

The containing block in your case is basically the parent element:

> The position and size of an element's box(es) are sometimes calculated relative to a certain rectangle, called the containing block of the element. The containing block of an element is defined as follows:
>
> ...
>
> 2. For other elements, if the element's position is 'relative' or 'static', the containing block is formed by the content edge of the nearest block container ancestor box. <sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#containing-block-details)</sup>

<sup>1</sup>More about replaced element:

> An element whose content is outside the scope of the CSS formatting model, such as an image or embedded document. For example, the content of the HTML img element is often replaced by the image that its src attribute designates. Replaced elements often have intrinsic dimensions: an intrinsic width, an intrinsic height, and an intrinsic ratio.  .. <sup>[ref](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-display/#replaced-element)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

If there are no width/height parameters, an image is displayed at its original size, regardless of the `display` setting, like in your example. If you want it to stretch to the full width of its container, you have to add `width: 100%`

```css
img {
  background-color: lightblue;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.d1 {
  background-color: blue;
}

.s1 {
  background-color: orange;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://placehold.it/50x20">
<div class="d1">Test1</div>
<span class="s1">Test2</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the img tag width is orientating on the image width you load. If you want to size it in block with full width you need to add the width attribute with a value of 100%. But you will see... the height of the image tag will also change to prevent the aspect-ratio.

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
<!--
img {
  background-color: lightblue;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.d1 {
  background-color: blue;
}

.s1 {
  background-color: orange;
  display: block;
}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
<img src="https://placehold.it/50x20">
<div class="d1">Test1</div>
<span class="s1">Test2</span>
</body>
</html>
```